# Trying to implement merge sort with some modifications

Tags: java, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort algorithm with some optimization like using temp storage only once and avoiding the copy till the last.Everything is okay and many test files are passing except some.The thing that is happening here is with unsorted array,the algorithm is showing some problems.I have written print statements in my code trying to reach the problem,but unable to do so.As many tests are passing,i believe there is nothing major wrong in the program,just it misses something.

I have tried to implement the program and it is successful in many ways,just 3 cases doesn't pass.But,the main problem i am facing is that test case Mergesort_two() doesn't pass because its simple .It's just calling two numbers and asserting in sorted form,but my program is denying it.I believe its a minor error which i am unable to figure out.

```
public static void mergesort(int[] input, int[] temp, 
                             int start, int end, 
                             boolean intoTemp) {
    if (start == end) {
        return; 
    }

    if ((start + 1) == end) {
        if (intoTemp == true) {
            temp[start] = input[start];
            return;
        }
    }

    if (start < end) {
        if (intoTemp == false) {
            intoTemp = true;
            int mid = (start + end)/2;

            mergesort(input, temp, start, mid, intoTemp);
            mergesort(input, temp, mid, end, intoTemp);

            merge(input, temp, start, mid, end);
            System.out.println("Input Array: " + Arrays.toString(input) + 
                    " Temp: " + Arrays.toString(temp) + " intoTemp: " +
                    intoTemp + "Start Mid End: " + start + " " + mid + " " + end);

        }
        else if(intoTemp == true) {
            intoTemp = false;
            int mid = (start + end)/2;

            mergesort(input, temp, start, mid, intoTemp);
            mergesort(input, temp, mid, end, intoTemp);

            merge(temp, input, start, mid, end);
            System.out.println("Input Array: " + Arrays.toString(input) + 
                    " Temp: " + Arrays.toString(temp) + " intoTemp: " +
                    intoTemp + "Start Mid End: " + start + " " + mid + " " + end);

        }
    }
    if (start == 0 && end == input.length) {
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, input, 0, input.length);
    }
}

/** Merges input[start...mid-1] with input[mid...end-1] into
 * output[start...end-1]. The input array should not be modified at
 * all, and only start...end-1 of the output array should be changed. 
 * 
 * @param input  Input array
 * @param output Output array
 * @param start  Starting index
 * @param mid    Midpoint index
 * @param end    Ending index+1
 */
public static void merge(int[] input, int[] output, 
                         int start, int mid, int end) {

    if (input == null || (start == mid && mid == end)) {
        return;
    }

    int i = start;
    int j = mid - 1;
    int k = mid;

    int index = start;

    while (i <= j && k < end) {
        if (input[i] <= input[k]) {
            output[index] = input[i];
            i++;
            index++;
        }
        if (input[i] > input[k]) {
            output[index] = input[i];
            k++;
            index++;
        }
    }    

    while (i <= j) {
        output[index] = input[i];
        index++;
        i++;
    }

    while (k < end) {
        output[index] = input[k];
        index++;
        k++;
    }
  }
}
```

////// Test Cases

```
 @Test
public void testMergesort_Two() {
    System.out.println("mergesort one element");
    int[] array = new int[2];

    // Already sorted
    array[0] = 10; array[1] = 13;       
    CSSE240_Assign4.mergesort(array);
    assertEquals(array[0], 10);
    assertEquals(array[1], 13);

    // Unsorted
    array[0] = 3; array[1] = -4;
    CSSE240_Assign4.mergesort(array);        
    assertEquals(array[0], -4);
    assertEquals(array[1], 3);        
}

@Test
public void testMergesort_Large() {
    System.out.println("mergesort one large");
    Random rng = new Random();

    for(int s = 3; s < 20; ++s) {

        int[] array = new int[s];
        int[] orig = new int[s];

        // Fill with random values.
        for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
            array[i] = rng.nextInt();
            orig[i] = array[i];
        }

        CSSE240_Assign4.mergesort(array);
        Arrays.sort(orig);

        // Make sure both arrays agree
        for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
            assertEquals(orig[i], array[i]);                                                
    }
}
@Test
public void testMergeInterleaved() {
    // Various cases where the left/right halves are interleaved. We test
    // this by picking a modulo m and moving all the elements where 
    // e % m < m/2 to the right side.
    System.out.println("merge reverse sorted");

    for(int s = 3; s < 20; ++s) {
        int[] array = new int[s];
        int mid = 0;       

        // Move the elements of the array around into the two halves.
        for(int m = 2; m < 5; ++m) {                

            // Populate the array with 0...s-1
            for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
                array[i] = i;
            }

            int[] left = new int[s];
            int[] right = new int[s];
            int lc = 0, rc = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
                if(array[i] % m < m/2) 
                    right[rc++] = array[i];
                else
                    left[lc++] = array[i];

            // Copy back into the array
            int j = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < lc; ++i)
                array[j++] = left[i];
            for(int i = 0; i < rc; ++i)
                array[j++] = right[i];

            mid = lc; // Midpoint            

            int[] output = new int[s];
            Arrays.fill(output, -1);

            // TODO: check different endpoints...
            CSSE240_Assign4.merge(array, output, 0, mid, s);

            for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
                assertEquals(output[i], i);
        }
    }
}       


testMergesort_Two Failed : expected <-4> but was <3>
testMergeInterleaved Failed: expected <0> but was <1>
testMergeSort_Large Failed : expected:<-1131373963> but was:<-2038582366>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes noted in comments.

```
    public static void mergesort(int[] input, int[] temp, 
                                 int start, int end, 
                                 boolean intoTemp) {
        if (start == end) {
            return; 
        }

        if ((start + 1) == end) {
            if (intoTemp == true) {
                temp[start] = input[start];
                return;
            }
        }

        if (intoTemp == false) {
            intoTemp = true;
            int mid = (start + end)/2;
            mergesort(input, temp, start, mid, intoTemp);
            mergesort(input, temp, mid, end, intoTemp);
            merge(temp, input, start, mid, end);
        } else {
            intoTemp = false;
            int mid = (start + end)/2;
            mergesort(input, temp, start, mid, intoTemp);
            mergesort(input, temp, mid, end, intoTemp);
            merge(input, temp, start, mid, end);
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int[] input, int[] output, 
                             int start, int mid, int end) {
        int i = start;
        int j = mid;                          // using j instead of k
                                              // and mid instead of j

        int index = start;

        while (i < mid && j < end) {          // using mid
            if (input[i] <= input[j]) {
                output[index] = input[i];
                i++;
                index++;
            } else {                          // change
                output[index] = input[j];     // was input[i]
                j++;
                index++;
            }
        }    

        while (i < mid) {                     // using mid
            output[index] = input[i];
            i++;                              // changed order for consistency
            index++;
        }

        while (j < end) {
            output[index] = input[j];
            j++;                              // changed order for consistency
            index++;
        }
    }
```